# Laravel Blade - orderBy

Tags: php, eloquent, sql-order-by, laravel-blade

I have this foreach loop in my blade template.

```
@foreach ($employee->projects->groupBy('stage') as $stage => $project)
  <tbody>
    <td>{{ $stage }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ count($project) }}</td>
  </tbody>
@endforeach
```

Where it finds all the projects that the employee is involved in and groups them by what stage they are in (Waiting, In Progress, Launched). And then it lists the stages and the count of how many are in each stage. This works perfectly but they are not in the right order. I would like them in Waiting, In Progress, Launched. Currently it's in Launched, Waiting, In Progress.

How can I order them in my custom order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured this out. Here's what I did...

```
$projects = $employee->projects()
        ->groupBy('stage')
        ->select('stage', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->orderByRaw('case 
            when stage = "Waiting" then 1 
            when stage = "In Progress" then 2 
            when stage = "Launched" then 3
            end')
        ->get();
```

Then in my blade template, I did...

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)
  <tbody>
    <td>{{ $project->stage }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ $project->total }}</td>
  </tbody>
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

SQL should be

```
  SELECT ... FROM projects GROUP BY stage 
    ORDER BY stage = 'Waiting' DESC, stage = 'In Progress', ...
```

probably you need use similar to this

```
  ->order_by(DB::expr("stage = 'Waiting' DESC"))->order_by(...)
```

Comment: Hi, can I do that query in the blade template? I think that has to be in the controller, right?  I have a foreach loop in the blade template that needs to be ordered.